# How to get a customUIItem in TestStackwhite where control type is ControlType.Pane

Tags: white-framework

I have a windows application in which few buttons are shown as pane in UISPY.

AutomationElement

General Accessibility

```
AccessKey:  ""

AcceleratorKey: ""

IsKeyboardFocusable:    "True"

LabeledBy:  "(null)"

HelpText:   ""
```

State

```
IsEnabled:  "True"

HasKeyboardFocus:   "False"
```

Identification

```
ClassName:  "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d"

ControlType:    "ControlType.Pane"

Culture:    "(null)"

AutomationId:   "2624504"

LocalizedControlType:   "pane"

Name:   "SAVE"

ProcessId:  "6892 (OATDT.ATA.SP.Home)"

RuntimeId:  "42 2624504"

IsPassword: "False"

IsControlElement:   "True"

IsContentElement:   "True"
```

Visibility

```
BoundingRectangle:  "(-31471, -31598, 104, 23)"

ClickablePoint: "(null)"

IsOffscreen:    "True"
```

ControlPatterns

How to get that pane and click that? Can any one please help

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try something like this

```
var pane = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("2624504"));

pane.Click();
```

This worked for me for the same

Answer (score 2):

Basically Panes are controls that do not expose automation patterns or have a specific automation type.

You can still get the bounds and such and click on the control, but White cannot give you a nice high level abstraction for Panes like it does for other controls